# Apache Camel SFTP File Upload is not working

Tags: java, apache-camel

Program is not throwing any exception but file is moved to .camel folder.It was not uploaded to the server location /tmp/uta/test1 .Also it says "Upload file ubuntu.png is complete.". Please help me to find what is wrong.

**Router:-**

```
@Component
public class SampleCamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:C:/Users/Downloads/test")
        .to("sftp://user@102.108.99.100/tmp/uta/test1?password=password").
         log("Upload file ${file:name} is complete.");
    }
}
```

**Updated Log details:-**

```
route starts..
route ends..

[0     ] - Apache Camel 2.13.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[4     ] - Tracing is enabled on CamelContext: camel-1
[5     ] - JMX is enabled
[370   ] - Loaded 175 type converters
[662   ] - AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
[662   ] - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[725   ] - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[file://C:/Users/Downloads/test]
[725   ] - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
[744   ] - Apache Camel 2.13.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.730 seconds
[31453 ] - ID-B20GPF2-59231-1501554606358-0-2 >>> (route1) from(file://C:/Users/Downloads/test) --> sftp://leo@102.108.99.100/tmp/uta/test1?password=xxxxxx <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{CamelFileName=cron.png, CamelFileNameOnly=cron.png, CamelFileRelativePath=cron.png, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileLength=4214, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Users\Downloads\test\cron.png, breadcrumbId=ID-B20GPF2-59231-1501554606358-0-1, CamelFileLastModified=1497248004376, CamelFileParent=C:\Users\Downloads\test, CamelFilePath=C:\Users\Downloads\test\cron.png, CamelFileNameConsumed=cron.png}, BodyType:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile, Body:[Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\Users\Downloads\test\cron.png]]
[31649 ] - JSCH -> Connecting to 102.108.99.100 port 22
[31685 ] - JSCH -> Connection established
[31703 ] - JSCH -> Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
[31703 ] - JSCH -> Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.50
[31703 ] - JSCH -> CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
[33657 ] - JSCH -> aes256-ctr is not available.
[33657 ] - JSCH -> aes192-ctr is not available.
[33657 ] - JSCH -> aes256-cbc is not available.
[33657 ] - JSCH -> aes192-cbc is not available.
[33657 ] - JSCH -> arcfour256 is not available.
[33658 ] - JSCH -> CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
[34313 ] - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
[34314 ] - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: 
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: server: 
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
[34314 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: none
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: none
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: 
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: client: 
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
[34315 ] - JSCH -> kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
[34337 ] - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
[34337 ] - JSCH -> expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
[34359 ] - JSCH -> ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
[34364 ] - JSCH -> Permanently added '102.108.99.100' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
[34365 ] - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
[34365 ] - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
[34374 ] - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
[34375 ] - JSCH -> SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
[34378 ] - JSCH -> Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
[34379 ] - JSCH -> Next authentication method: publickey
[34380 ] - JSCH -> Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
[34380 ] - JSCH -> Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
[34396 ] - JSCH -> Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
[34904 ] - Connected to sftp://leo@102.108.99.100:22
[34904 ] - Connected and logged in to: Endpoint[sftp://leo@102.108.99.100/tmp/uta/test1?password=xxxxxx]
[34950 ] - ID-B20GPF2-59231-1501554606358-0-2 >>> (route1) sftp://leo@102.108.99.100/tmp/uta/test1?password=xxxxxx --> log[Upload file ${file:name} is complete.] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{CamelFileRelativePath=cron.png, breadcrumbId=ID-B20GPF2-59231-1501554606358-0-1, CamelFileLastModified=1497248004376, CamelFileLength=4214, CamelFileName=cron.png, CamelFileNameConsumed=cron.png, CamelFileNameProduced=tmp/uta/test1/cron.png, CamelFileParent=C:\Users\Downloads\test, CamelFileNameOnly=cron.png, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFilePath=C:\Users\Downloads\test\cron.png, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Users\Downloads\test\cron.png}, BodyType:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile, Body:[Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\Users\Downloads\test\cron.png]]
[34950 ] - Upload file cron.png is complete.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, camel will always go to `/home/username/` dir and then will open your provided directory path.
So, it will be relative path.
You can not provide absolute path directly, so use `/../../tmp/uta/test1` and `stepwise=true`

For better insights, you can also try:
`runLoggingLevel=TRACE`, `throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true` and other options.

Answer (score 3):

The file is moved to `.camel` sub folder on the computer where you run the Camel application. That is how the Camel file component work out of the box (see the move option).

The FTP component that are used in your Camel route is supposed to upload the file. So have you checked on the FTP server side, if there is a file uploaded. You can check the logs from the FTP server.

You can also try enabling DEBUG/TRACE logging on Camel application to see what is being logged.

Comment: thanks for reply, I know first files will be moved to .camle but problem am facing is it is not uploading to the server also there is no error.Please find the updated TRACE details.

Comment: thanks for your guidance to debug but in logs it is not showing where exactly is upload happened.

Answer (score 0):

File is uploaded to the Server successfully but location is different.

```
Location to route :user@102.108.99.100/tmp/uta/test1
Location routed :user@102.108.99.100/home/user/tmp/uta/test1
```

It is creating the uploading directory inside the user home directory that is the reason it is not available in expected directory.