# Give relative directory from root at SFTP camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

Here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46031222/13268597

you can see. He says

> By default, camel will always go to /home/username/ dir and then will
> open your provided directory path. So, it will be relative path.

I am connecting with this:

```java
from("sftp://"
    // + username + "@"
    + hostAddress
    + ":22" 
    + "/home/username"
    + "/POLICE_BELGE_MUTABAKAT/GUNLUK/" //path
    // + "&"
    + "?username=" + username
```

When i do this, it cant go because the destination it connected at first is already **/home/username**

So, when i change that

```java
from("sftp://"
    // + username + "@"
    + hostAddress
    + ":22"
    // + "/home/username"  //here commented
    + "/POLICE_BELGE_MUTABAKAT/GUNLUK/" //path
    // + "&" +
    + "?username=" + username
    + "&password=" + password
    + "&fileName=f1.txt"
```

it works because file is in that path:

```
/home/username/POLICE_BELGE_MUTABAKAT/GUNLUK/
```

Those are other parameters:

```java
    + "&fileName=f1.txt"
    + "&autoCreate=false"
    + "&strictHostKeyChecking=no"
    + "&preferredAuthentications=publickey,password"
    + "&stepwise=false"
    + "&streamDownload=true"
```

I also tried to make **stepwise=true** but did not work.

On linux machines, it goes `/home/username/` at first but for other machines, it is going to `/` path.

So, are there any ways to give the path from `"/"` without giving hardcoded values?

Answer (score 3):

No, the path used in `ftp`, `ftps` and `sftp` components is always relative to FTP home directory of logged in user.

See [Ftp Component documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html):

> Absolute path is **not** supported. Camel translates absolute path to relative by trimming all leading slashes from `directoryname`.

> The directory name is a relative path. Absolute path’s is **not** supported. The relative path can contain nested folders, such as /inbox/us.

Comment: But when i connect so some servers, there are no folders of username so it stays at root, "/"

Comment: FTP home can be different from Linux user home. FTP home directory depends on configuration of FTP server. In some configurations it can be seemingly "/", but it is in most cases just `chroot`.